# HTML/CSS - How to center the middle div out of three, independent of surrounding divs

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I am developing a small site with dropdown menus, using only HTML/CSS. In itself this works fine. I used to use TD's, but hey, DIVS rules, so using DIVs now.

I use a topmenu. On the left hand side, there is a number of menu items and the same goes for the rights hand side of the menu. So far all good. Since there is only two divs, one floating left and one floating right, and both have the same CSS applying within a containmer div with width 100%, it looks like one big menu bar.

The problem arises when I want to add a small logo in EXACTLY the middle of the screen, on the same menu bar. Since the left and right menu option list aren't exactly the same width (the right hand side menu item list is somewhat shorter), the logo in the middle is skewed to the right.

To make things worse, the list of menu options is dynamic, depending on what page you are on and wether you are logged in.

What I want to achieve is this:

- Have 3 parts on the menu bar: right menu, middle logo, left menu
- The middle logo must always be in the exact center of the screen
- When resizing the browser window, the left & right part resize automatically to fit the screen
- the middle logo is fixed width
- When resizing, the left and right menu may only resize to the width required by the longest of the right or right menu options list
- Of course, no wrapping!

I have been trying but fail miserably, mainly because my knowledge is insufficient. I prewfer to only use HTML/CSS and not JS/jquery

I tried having a backgorund image in the css of the container div, but then, when resizing, the menu options eventually flow over the middle log.

THis is teh CSS for the dropdown menus (got it from the web somewhere, not my code)

```
.navbarl {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  }

.navbarl a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  }

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 12px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  }

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  }

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  }

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  }

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  }
```

The HTML normally looks something like this:

```
<div class="navbarl">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I changed this for my site of course, and added a second block of this for the right hand side menu on the menu bar.

THis is what I now have for the complete menu bar. I know tables are bad for formatting stuff, but I have tried many different things, and this is a copy of my last attempt. As I said, I am still new to divs and learning to get rid of them :-)

```
<table class=menu>
  <tr>
    <td class="menu_left">
      <div class="navbarl">
        <a href="/index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="/somesubfolder/index.php">Menu option 2 wih a long name</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Cursus&#9660;</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/somesubfolder/a.php">Be</a>
            <a href="/somesubfolder/b.php">One</a>
          </div>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        </div>
        <a href="/misc/login.php">Login</a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="menu_middle">
      <a href="http://www.budgetbytes.nl"><img class="menu_sponsor" src="/images/sponsor.png" alt=""/></a>
    </td>
    <td class="menu_right">
      <div class="navbarl">
        <a href="/misc/nieuws.php">Nieuws</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is an example (logo i made invisible, no need to be commercial here, its our sponsors logo). You can see its skewed

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Yes, will take some time, I am not yet very familiar with the site, need to figure out code blocks :P

Comment: go edit your post and remove the `<p>` tag I added  and add your html instead.

Comment: @adam I think I got the code blocks working, sorry for the newbie level :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where `flexbox` comes in really handy. I would advise you to stay away from using `table` for layouts because it would be used incorrectly, just as `float` is meant only for placing images to the side of text.

I have made a quick, simple example of how a navigation menu could be created with `flexbox`. Naturally, you will want to create a mobile menu at smaller viewport widths.

**HTML**

```
<header role="navigation">
    <div class="nav menu nav1">
        <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="menu-item">Home</a>
        <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="menu-item">News</a>
        <div class="menu-dropdown menu-item">
            <p tabindex="0">Dropdown</p>
            <a href="#" tabindex="0">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#" tabindex="0">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#" tabindex="0">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu logo">
        <a href="#" tabindex="0" title="Click to go to homepage">
            <img src="http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/blue-eyed-husky-puppy-picture-id178375154?s=170x170&w=1007" alt="Husky puppy">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav menu nav2">
        <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="menu-item">About</a>
        <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="menu-item">Contact</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS (scss)**

```
header {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;

    .nav {
        width: 42.5%;
    }

    .logo {
        width: 15%;
    }

    .menu {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;

        .menu-dropdown {
            height: 20px;
            margin-bottom: -5px;

            p {
                cursor: pointer;
                margin: 0;

                &:focus, &:hover {
                    ~ a {
                        display: block;
                    }
                }
            }

            a {
                display: none;
            }

            &:focus, &:hover {
                height: 70px;
                margin-bottom: -55px;

                a {
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }

        img {
            width: 100px;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjXaVW

**Explanation**

`Flexbox` is a CSS layout technique that uses the browser's CSS engine to dynamically arrange elements. Instead of having to assign widths manually, `flexbox` does the heavy lifting for us.

[Learn More about Flexbox](https://cssreference.io/flexbox/)

```
.some-random-class {
    align-items: center; // I'm telling the element to arrange its children to be vertically centered
    display: flex; // Declaring that this element will be using flexbox; it's like flipping the "Flexbox Switch" to on.
    flex-wrap: nowrap; // I'm telling the element to never allow its children to wrap (i.e. fold over). Using "wrap" instead of "nowrap" tells the element to definitely allow its children to wrap (i.e. fold over)
    justify-content: center; // I'm telling the element to horizontally center its children. There are more options than just "center"
}
```

With the `justify-content: center;`, the menu and logo will always be centered on the page. Notice that the `<div class='menu logo'></div>` element is in between the other two `div` elements, and these two other `div` elements contain menu items.

Comment: Ok, this looks promising looking at the example. I just have a few points./ First of all i am quite new to CSS and this is a bit complex for me. Could you give me a really short explanation of what you did? I also seem to be missing a few classes like nav1 in the css. Is this for a reason?

And one more thing: Right now you space out the menu items. Is it possible to have the menuitems a fixed width apart from each other, and aligned left (the left menu) and right (the right menu)? Please if I am unclear, look at the example picture i added in my Opening POst

Comment: Updated. I'll give you the opportunity to play around with the menu items and space them out specifically. There are countless guides, videos, etc. on flexbox, so use those. The classes that I added were only used as an example; I follow the DRY (don't repeat yourself) method when using CSS, which classes come in handy. Notice that all the `div` elements have `menu` as a class, only the `div` elements with menu items have the `nav` class, and `nav1` and `nav2` are for the two menu items.